# Any way to prevent iOS Enterprise app from fully terminating after crash?

Tags: xcode, ios5, crash

Preface: I write iPad apps for a museum to be used as "permanant" informational kiosks. They need to run 1 app all the time. My question pertains to this situation and not App Store distribution or worrying about out-of-house users as these are enterprise apps. I am the only developer and am still new to app development, operate under strict deadlines and can't always fix every bug before the app has to go on the floor. Our guests are sometimes the app's intial testers. These are iPad 2's and new's running iOS 5.1. Some apps are running the Cocos2d ver 2.0 framework.

I need to prevent museum guests from even getting to the iPad's desktop. I have disabled the home button using a mobileconfig file after finding out about `SBStoreDemoAppLock` and with a metal frame enclosure. Obviously I want, and work towards, my apps never crashing. However, when the iPads are running 24/7 and sometimes deal with 2000+ children tapping, swiping, and beating on them per day, the app does occasionally crash.

As I work on better coding to prevent crashes from even happening, is there any way to prevent an app from fully closing if it experiences a crash? Meaning if it needs to crash, can a simple imageView be displayed saying "contact IT"? I know that sounds contradictory, because if an app needs to crash, it's going to crash, but I'm not sure how else to word it.

Alternatively, and even less likely, is there a way to relaunch the app automagically after a crash? I've looked into the URL scheme approach and adding that to `applicationWillTerminate`, however that has been deprecated since iOS 4 came on the scene. I prefer to avoid jailbreaking, but if someone knows a dead easy way to do this with a Cydia app, I'd like to hear about it as a last resort option.

I have the iPads fully restricted as far as is available under the settings tab, but kids (and adults) today can find all sorts of things to mess up, such as inverting colors, turning on assisted zoom, etc.

Comment: A real crash (as opposed to an uncaught exception) is presented as a particular signal (IIRC, SIGBUS or SIGSEGV) that's sent to your app. You can actually catch this signal and do stuff, but it's very tricky, because if this happens, you cannot rely on *anything* in the runtime to be correct (IIRC, not even malloc). I'm not really sure what you could do effectively in such a signal handler.

Comment: I don't know if it will work, but take a look at launchd to KeepAlive your application. See `man launchd` and `man launchd.plist` on Mac OS X for more info.

Comment: @lef2: App plists aren't launchd plists.

Comment: @KevinBallard could you explain the difference between a "real crash" and an uncaught exception? Or point me in the direction of a definition? One of my problems is not being present during these crashes and I can't duplicate it on my personal iPad. Does the iPad maintain a crash log over a period of days or is it gone the next time the app opens? Sorry...that's a lot of questions for a comment.

Comment: @BobbyScon: An uncaught exception will terminate the app, but that's not the same thing as, say, dereferencing NULL, or some other illegal operation.

Comment: @BobbyScon You can see downloaded crash logs in the [XCode Organiser](http://xinsight.ca/blog/a-long-road-to-a-simple-solution/).

Comment: @Douglas Yeah, that's a good call. Unfortunately, some of the time, I find that I'm not always informed if an app has crashed at all. Sometimes other staff members see the app down and reload it for me. Some of them tell me, others don't. I haven't found the documentation yet, but do you happen to know how long/many crash logs are kept on the device and do they remain after rebooting?

Comment: I can't find any docs for how long the log files stay on the system, though I don't believe that they are deleted on reboot. I'd say plug one in and give it a try, the age of the oldest log file will give you an idea of how long they are around for.

Comment: OFF-TOPIC: Have you found a way to also launch the app automatically? I mean, I did the whole SBStoreDemoAppLock thing but I still haven't found a way to launch the app automatically at startup.

Comment: @ygbr From all of my research, the only thing that I've found is that it's only possible if you JailBreak, it's still extremely difficult, and it's not reliable. iOS 6 is introducing a new feature where kiosk mode is built in via a 3x home button hit so parents can keep their kids within an app. It's turned on and off via passcode. I don't know if auto-launch will be in this feature set as well.

Comment: @ygbr, after thinking about it, how would you ever turn off the app? If you disable the home button (using the demo method, not the iOS6 method), the only way to exit the app is by rebooting the iPad. But with auto-app launch, rebooting would just relaunch the app. You could never get into settings to remove the config file, and if you've disabled the home button, you've most likely disabled multi-gesture. You're stuck with an iPad that can't ever leave the app unless you hook it up to a computer.

Comment: @BobbyScon well ideally in order to stop the app from auto-loading you should plug it into a mac and remove the provisioning profile from the device, so after rebooting the app would not load automatically anymore. Jailbreak is not a solution when you are on enterprise environments and need to scale your solution. I have high hopes with iOS6, I'm running it on my devices as I am a registered Apple Dev but can't comment on it publicly until the official release.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that comes to mind is to use NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler to intercept any errors in the apps.  Whatever you do in the handler should involve the least code possible, have any resources it needs pre-loaded, and be well tested since errors during exception handling are a **bad** idea.

Comment: Crashes aren't necessarily uncaught exceptions.

Comment: @KevinBallard - Which is why I said 'first thing'.  :)